# Helper class for sqlite database doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite

I used the following code in my activity, which checks for database errors and works just fine:

```
//DB Test
        Boolean databaseError = false;
        SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("myDB", 0, null);        
        try {
             myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM occasions;", null);
             myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM instrumentations;", null); 
             myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM editions;", null); 
             myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM composers;", null); 
             myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM compositions;", null); 
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("SQLiteException", "SQLiteException");
            databaseError = true;       
        }
        myDB.close();
```

I want to put the code in the following helper class:

```
public abstract class BackupHelper {

public static boolean checkDB() {
    Boolean databaseError = false;
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
    myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("myDB", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);        
    try {
         myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM occasions;", null);
         myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM instrumentations;", null); 
         myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM editions;", null); 
         myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM composers;", null); 
         myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM compositions;", null); 
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("SQLiteException", "SQLiteException");
        databaseError = true;       
    }
    myDB.close();
    return databaseError;
}
```

}

But this throws the following error:

> 02-26 21:13:16.397: E/MyTestDatabase(29244): sqlite3_open_v2("myDB", &handle, 2, NULL) failed
>   02-26 21:13:17.048: E/AndroidRuntime(29244): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the Database before try to open it.

Create a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class DBCreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // region Properties

    private final static String tag = "DBCreator";

    // endregion

    // region Constructors

    public DBCreator(String name, int version) {
        super(ABApplication.getContext(), name, null, version);
    }

    public DBCreator(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public DBCreator(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
    }

    // endregion

    // region Overrides
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // Execute your CREATE Table script
    }

    // endregion 

}
```

Then you can retrieve a SQLiteDatabase instance in this way:

```
 SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDatabase = new DBCreator(context, dbName, null, 1) getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Thank you. I already had a class extending sqliteopenhelper but didn't use it ;-) Now it works.